# How to implement a "fire-and-forget" async call in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

I am reviewing/cleaning up some Android code. The code did some "asynchronous" network and data operations using this pattern:

```
new Thread() { public void run() { { ... runOnUiThread( { .. } ) }
```

A lot. With all the ugly consequences (no error checks, Sleeps, boolean `finish` variables...).

Till now, I ended up using (few) `AsyncTasks` and (more) `Loaders` as replacements.

Now I have stumbled upon a couple of "fire-and-forget" network communications: the code (currently, a Thread, as always) calls a web service posting some data.
I do not need to know if the data was received, and I do not need to know if there was any error.

Which is the best way of doing this? A `Runnable` or `AsyncTask` (static nested class, so I do not "leak" a reference to "this" activity?)

Or is there something better (more "lightweight" and cleaner?)

Comment: I would go with `IntentService` - It runs in the background in it's own thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to know when task execution is finished then you definitely don't need `AsyncTask` at all. Therefore the most lightweight  solution is just a `Thread`. You can use `Executor` which will create threads for you. To get rid of nested classes you could predefine tasks. Sample:

Predefined task:

```
public static class TaskA implements Runnable{

    private int someParam;

    public TaskA(int someParam) {
        this.someParam = someParam;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //
    }
}
```

Static `Executor`

```
public static class FireAndForgetExecutor{

    private static Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public static void exec(Runnable command){
        executor.execute(command);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
FireAndForgetExecutor.exec(new TaskA(10));
```

**PS** don't forget that a `Thread` is connected to the GC root! So if you pass heavy object like an activity or a bitmap into the task it could lead to memory leak.

Comment: I adopted a variant of this solution. Quite neat! Thanks!